# Google map with 1000 marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I am adding google map marker with 1000 marker in small boundery box, while moving map arround, app frezzing, didn't know why,
Also i have tried marker cluster . but client has refuesed it, he need all marker to be shown on map, as marker is mandetory to show to user...!
is there any way to do so with better preformance
i figure that may i zoom in to custom point and show marker only with boundry box map, and while user move map he remove marker around and put new marker 
but this will come on looping in array with 1000 element in it, and this is n't better solution, any one know how to do so !!!?

```
for (int i = 0; i < stopDetailsModelResponses.size(); i++) {
   mapHelper.setMarkerPinWithLayoutToImage(
                    stopDetailsModelResponses.get(i).getStopDetailsLat(),
                    stopDetailsModelResponses.get(i).getStopDetailsLong(),
                    stopDetailsModelResponses.get(i).getStopDetailsName(),
                    String.valueOf(stopDetailsModelResponses.get(i).getStopDetailsId()),
                    stopDetailsModelResponses.get(i).getStopDetailsLogoUrl(),
                    stopDetailsModelResponses.get(i).getStopDetailsType(),
                    markerOptions, googleMap, getContext()
            );
        }
  googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(onMarkerClickListener);
```

this for looping inside list to set element to map marker

and this for adding marker to map

```
try {
            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(lat, longitude))
                    .title(locationName)
                    .draggable(false);
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(defineLayoutOfPin(context, imageType, locationId)));
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("setMarkerWithImage: ", e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: plus are you dynamically adding markers ?

Comment: yes i dynamically adding marker to map

Comment: If clustering is not an option and you need to dynamically add/remove from map on zoom/scroll, then geohashing will work for you.  With geohashing you can use current center location and screen projection to access only the markers needed for current display.  There is a geohash library that is very simple to use: https://github.com/drfonfon/android-geohash